# jquery trimming empty spaces at the end of string

Tags: jquery, texttrimming

what is the easiest way to trim empty spaces from the end of a string in jquery/javascript?
example:
`"my string    "` should return `"my string"`

thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) will trim leading and trailing spaces from a string :

```
str = $.trim(str);
```

There's also the native `trim()` method that is supported in newer browsers, and there's a polyfill available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) for non-supporting browsers.

If for some reason you only want to trim trailing spaces, you can do something like :

```
String.prototype.trimTrail = function () {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/, '');
};
```

to be used as :

```
str = str.trimTrail();
```

Comment: sorry but i actually meant trimming trailing spaces not leading .. :)

Comment: added something for trailing spaces only ?

Comment: @Fuxi you should put what you actually meant in the question so you get the answer you actually want

Answer (score 0):

Try this to replicate a right trim:

var trimmedString = fullString.replace(/\s+$/,”");